# Laravel collection sort by property value inside property array

Tags: php, laravel

I have a query that returns the following collection.

```
[0]=>{
    ['title']=>'Title 1',
    ['description']=>'Desc 1',
    ['meta']=>Array(
        [0]=>{
            ['meta_key']=>'some_key',
            ['meta_value']=>'some value',
        },
        [1]=>{
            ['meta_key']=>'key_date',
            ['meta_value']=>20171012,
        }
    ),    
},
[1]=>{
    ['title']=>'Title 2',
    ['description']=>'Desc 2',
    ['meta']=>Array(
        [0]=>{
            ['meta_key']=>'key_date',
            ['meta_value']=>20170612,
        }
    ),    
},
[2]=>{
    ['title']=>'Title 3',
    ['description']=>'Desc 3',
    ['meta']=>Array(
        [0]=>{
            ['meta_key']=>'key_date',
            ['meta_value']=>20171112,
        },
        [1]=>{
            ['meta_key']=>'some_key',
            ['meta_value']=>'some_value',
        }
    ),    
}
```

What I want is to sort the collection by the key_date inside meta in descending order and then grab the first entry. the key_date value is in Ymd format. So, in this case I will get the [2].

I am using Laravel 4.2